# В чем разница между -webkit-animation-delay и просто animation-delay?

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation, webkit

Пытался анимировать кнопку.
Нашел сниппет в котором имеется такой код:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.75s;
```

Однако работает и без -webkit-. В чем разница?

Comment: Информация [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Comment: @IgorR. является ли это хорошей практикой писать префиксы для всех браузеров? Как указано у вас в ссылке `-webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 4s ease;
-ms-transition: all 4s ease;
-o-transition: all 4s ease;
transition: all 4s ease; `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-webkit-, -moz-, -ms- - префиксы браузеров. Без них браузер может обработать не так/не обработать некоторые css свойства. Дополнительно можете почитать [тут](https://itchief.ru/lessons/html-and-css/css-browser-prefixes).
Узнать, какие свойства нуждаются в префиксах можно [тут](https://caniuse.com/)